# Render quality is very low

Tags: animation, eevee-render-engine, scene

So im trying to render my 11s scene using eeve in blender
-Actual Quality below-
[image]

but when I start to render in png sequence using eeve,the quality looks like,
[image]

are there any settings that needs to be adjusted im missing ?pls help

camera settings
[image]

render settings
[image]

Comment: can you show us your render and camera settings? OR even share your file? At first it looks like problem that is cause by clip start and end of camera, or maybe it is shadows setting

Comment: @MikoCG I added them

Comment: Okay, how big is your scene in m*m? You are using clip end 9500 and clip start 0.1, is it needed? Try to set it to 0.1 and 1000 and say if something changed... also 512px and 1024px shadows may cause shadow appearing as little cubes, try to set it to at least 2048 and 2048 or even 4096 (this will make renders longer)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.